# Send only the ddropdownButton value to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a file called belt_controller_page.dart to use dropdownButton on the profile modification page and created a dropdownButton from it
On the Modify Profile page, type belt_controller(), and you will see dropdownButton.

What should I do to send only the dropdownButton value of belt_controller_page.dart to the profile modification page?

```
class belt_controller extends StatefulWidget {
  const belt_controller({super.key});

  @override
  State<belt_controller> createState() => _belt_controllerState();
}

class _belt_controllerState extends State<belt_controller> {

  ///Belt Controllers
  List<String> dropdownList = ['white', 'blue', 'purple', 'brown', 'black'];
  String selectedDropdown = 'white';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 5),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: DropdownButton(
          hint: Text('belt'),
          value: selectedDropdown,
          focusColor: Colors.grey,
          dropdownColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          isExpanded: true,
          underline: SizedBox(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 17,
          ),
          items: dropdownList.map((String item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              child: Text('$item'),
              value: item,
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (dynamic belt_value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedDropdown = belt_value;
              print(belt_value);
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
class profile_reset_page extends StatefulWidget {

  profile_reset_page({super.key});

  @override
  State<profile_reset_page> createState() => _profile_reset_pageState();
}

class _profile_reset_pageState extends State<profile_reset_page> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  
                  belt_controller(),
                  
                  const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  jiujitsuProfileButton(
                    text: 'Change',
                    TextColor: Colors.white,
                    BackgroundColor: Colors.red[300],
                    onTap: upDateUser,
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Attempted to change

```
onChanged: (dynamic belt_value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedDropdown = belt_value;
              print(belt_value);
            });
          },
```

value to

```
onChanged: (dynamic belt_value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedDropdown = belt_value;
              print(belt_value);
              profile_reset_page(belt_value:belt_value);
            });
          },
```

in belt_controller_page.belt_controller,
And after final belt_value in profile_reset_page.dat, required this.belt_value was not successful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the callback function to the `belt_controller` from the parent widget `profile_reset_page`.

**belt_controller**

```html
class belt_controller extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(String value) onSelected;       <--- Define a callback function that get fired when an item is selected.
  const belt_controller({super.key, required this.onSelected});

  @override
  State<belt_controller> createState() => _belt_controllerState();
}

class _belt_controllerState extends State<belt_controller> {

  ///Belt Controllers
  List<String> dropdownList = ['white', 'blue', 'purple', 'brown', 'black'];
  String selectedDropdown = 'white';


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 5),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1),
          color: Colors.grey[200],
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: DropdownButton(
          hint: Text('belt'),
          value: selectedDropdown,
          focusColor: Colors.grey,
          dropdownColor: Colors.grey.shade400,
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
          isExpanded: true,
          underline: SizedBox(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 17,
          ),
          items: dropdownList.map((String item) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              child: Text('$item'),
              value: item,
            );
          }).toList(),
          onChanged: (String belt_value) {
            setState(() {
              selectedDropdown = belt_value;
            });
            widget.onSelected(belt_value) <---- callback function executed
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**profile_reset_page**

```html
class profile_reset_page extends StatefulWidget {

  profile_reset_page({super.key});

  @override
  State<profile_reset_page> createState() => _profile_reset_pageState();
}

class _profile_reset_pageState extends State<profile_reset_page> {
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SizedBox(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  
                  belt_controller(
                     onSelected: (String value) {
                       print(value);                 <--- HERE you get the selected belt on change
                     }
                  ),
                  
                  const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  jiujitsuProfileButton(
                    text: 'Change',
                    TextColor: Colors.white,
                    BackgroundColor: Colors.red[300],
                    onTap: upDateUser,
                  ),
                ]
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```